# How to use Inner join on doctrine

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

User table

```
id name sex
1  john female
2  bob  male
3  tom  female
```

Schedule table

```
id title
2  work     // bob goes to work
2  shopping 
3  shopping // tom goes to shopping
1  work
```

Schedule.id is foreign key of User.

I wanto select rows from user table that 
the people who has the schedule to go shopping

```
2  bob male
3  tom female
```

How can I do like this ?

This is my cord for now,
it can select rows from schedule table.
but  I wanto select rows from User table.
I think inner join is important though,,,,,

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
SELECT p 
FROM UserBundle:Sche p 
WHERE p.title = 'shopping') ;

$result = $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
    SELECT a.id, a.name, a.sex, b.title
    FROM User a
    INNER JOIN 
    Schedule b ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE b.title = 'shopping'
);
$result = $query->getResult();
```